# need to eliminate dupe in joins and union

Tags: oracle, union, outer-join

Can Anyone help me out in this

```
query::
select Ext_Acct,date_opened,last_date_flown,Sender from
table1 T1,table2 T2
where T1.Ext_acct(+)=T2.Ext_acct
union
select Ext_Acct,date_opened,last_date_flown,Sender from
table1 T1,table2 T3
where T1.Ext_acct(+)=T3.Ext_acct
```

Data I have ::

Table1

```
Ext_Acct    date opened last date flown
AAA dd/mm/yyyy  dd/mm/yyyy
BBB dd/mm/yyyy  dd/mm/yyyy
CCC dd/mm/yyyy  dd/mm/yyyy
```

Table2

```
Ext_Acct    Sender  
AAA XXX
```

Table3

```
Ext_Acct    Sender  
BBB YYY 
CCC XXX
```

Expected Result::

```
Ext Acct    date opened last date flown Sender
AAA dd/mm/yyyy  dd/mm/yyy   XXX
BBB dd/mm/yyyy  dd/mm/yyy   YYY
CCC dd/mm/yyyy  dd/mm/yyy   XXX
```

Result got::

```
Ext Acct    date opened last date flown Sender
AAA dd/mm/yyyy  dd/mm/yyy   XXX
AAA         
BBB dd/mm/yyyy  dd/mm/yyy   YYY
BBB         
CCC dd/mm/yyyy  dd/mm/yyy   XXX
CCC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a union on T2 and T3

```
select t1.Ext_Acct,
        t1.date_opened,
        t1.last_date_flown,
        t2.Sender 
from
      table1 T1,
       (select Ext_Acct, Sender from Table2 
        union 
        select Ext_Acct, Sender from Table3) T2
where T1.Ext_Acct=T2.Ext_Acct(+)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try DISTINCT

```
select DISTINCT T1.Ext_Acct,T1.date_opened,T1.last_date_flown,T2.Sender from
table1 T1,table2 T2
where T1.Ext_acct(+)=T2.Ext_acct
union
select T1.Ext_Acct,T1.date_opened,T1.last_date_flown,T3.Sender from
table1 T1,table2 T3
where T1.Ext_acct(+)=T3.Ext_acct
```

but I suggest refrain from using IMPLICIT JOINS and start using the EXPLICIT JOINS as it is more accurate when there are loads of data.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.Ext_Acct,T1.date_opened,T1.last_date_flown,T2.Sender 
FROM TABLE1 T1 RIGHT JOIN TABLE2 T2
ON T1.Ext_acct = T2.Ext_acct
UNION
SELECT  T1.Ext_Acct,T1.date_opened,T1.last_date_flown,T3.Sender 
FROM TABLE1 T1 RIGHT JOIN TABLE3 T3
ON T1.Ext_acct = T3.Ext_acct
```